# foreach and multidimensional arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to make some table out of a multidimensional array

here is my code

http://pastebin.com/d13d62098

I am getting this error
**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

here is an example of the array

www.pastebin.com/m3454956a

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have an array keyed by TAC between your top array and the employee data. Easily fixed:

```
foreach ($employees as $tac) {
  $emp = $tac['TAC'];
  echo $emp['fname']." ".$emp['lname'];
  echo "<table>";
  foreach($emp['appts'] as $cli => $appts) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$cli</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
}
```

If TAC isn't some kind of constant (eg it's some kind of ID) then the solution will differ but there's not enough information to determine that.

Comment: It is an id.
Here is the url to the full code I have
www.pastebin.com/d13d62098

I tried that fix but it now won't even echo the name